# Symfony - check multiaccount entity belonging

Tags: symfony

I'm developing a dynamic multiaccount Platform in Symphony.

Each account will have a specific subdomain to access his site:

- www.account1.mydomain.com
- www.account2.mydomain.com

etc.etc.

The model has Entities related to the accounts. Some Entities have direct relations with the Account entity (Entity1 --> Account), some others have a chain of entities to connect to the Account entity (Entity2 --> Entity1 --> Account).

I have to be sure that Entities belonging to one Account cannot be accessed from another Account. Suppose this scenario:

```
$myAccount = new Account();
$myaccount->host = "www.myaccount.mydomain.com";

$myEntity = new Entity1();
$myEntity->id = 100;
$myEntity->account = $myAccount;
```

I want to display correctly the url www.**myaccount**.mydomain.com/show-entity-**100**, but return 404 if I try to access the Entity from a different Account/host

Of course I can perform checks in each Controller, but I think there is a better way. 
Is there something like a SecurityVoter where I can vote if an host can access a specific Entity?

What is the best practice to handle a check like this?

Thank you

Comment: Do it like [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/voters.html) and inject the **request_stack** service to get the host in the voter.

Comment: But a voter returns 403, not 404.

Comment: Is this the best practice to solve this problem? I do't have any example where Security Voters are used out of User scope.

Comment: Yes you can use voters without the user.